# Select first menu item by default

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to implement select menu which uses enum data to display data and saves number based on the selected String:

I tried this:

ENUM:

```
export enum MerchantStateType {
  being_set_up = 1,
  live_for_processing = 2,
  trading_suspended = 3,
  account_suspended = 4,
}

export const MerchantStateType2LabelMapping = {
  [MerchantStateType.being_set_up]: "Being set up",
  [MerchantStateType.live_for_processing]: "Live for processing",
  [MerchantStateType.trading_suspended]: "Trading suspended",
  [MerchantStateType.account_suspended]: "Account suspended",
}
```

Component:

```
public MerchantStateType2LabelMapping = MerchantStateType2LabelMapping;

public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType);
```

HTML code:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="merchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
      <!--<option selected></option>-->
      <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}</option>
```

How I can select by default the first menu item?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can add the following in ngOnInit()

```
this.merchant.state_raw = this.stateTypes[0]
```

(or) You can use local variable 'first' of *ngFor

```
<select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="merchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
      <!--<option selected></option>-->
      <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes; first as isFirst" [selected]="isFirst">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial value where ever you want ngOnInit() , Constructor():

```
this.merchant.state_raw = 1;
```

the state_raw holds the index of the enum.
Your select looks like this:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="marchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
  <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}
    </option>
    </select>
```

Modify your component from:

```
public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType);
```

To:

> ```
>  public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType).filter(type =>
>     isNumber(<any>type)
>   );
> ```

This will remove your id's from your values and get only the string

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
 <select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="current" id="state_raw" required>
          <!--<option selected></option>-->
          <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}</option>
```

Ts:

```
public current = 1;
```

Now the value of the select field you will get it with the variable `this.current`.